# Searching my own unanswered questions over all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, search, data-explorer, unanswered-questions

I wish to get a list of my own unanswered questions over all Stack Exchange sites.

It seems you can run SQL queries with [data.stackexchange.com](https://data.stackexchange.com/), something I learned only today. Is there a way I can use this to find all of my unanswered questions?

Comment: Just to be sure: unanswered means 1) no answers at all, 2) [no upvoted or accepted answers](/questions?tab=Unanswered), 3) something else?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here you go:

[Unanswered questions network-wide for a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1674797/unanswered-questions-network-wide-for-a-specific-user?AccountId=499285)

[image]

SEDE is updated only once a week, on Sunday morning, so the results might be a bit stale.

Comment: Worth to mention that the data is not live, you won't see questions asked in the current week. While trivial for us, some still don't know that. (I think @rene has some canned SEDE disclaimer)

Comment: @ShadowTheKidWizard thanks - that's in my usual SEDE disclaimer but I forgot about it, probably because a meeting just started and/or I've been away for a couple of weeks :)